# Error calculating and validating 100.000 with specific combination

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an interesting problem that I would like to share with you all. On a form we have repeating rows with percent allocation. In the end all the rows combined need to equal 100.000 (or 100%). If it does then it passes validation and the form can be submitted. It is a requirement that we go out 3 decimal points.

But with the following combination the form fails to meet validation. It is really odd.

- Row 1: 63.877
- Row 2: 34.286
- Row 3: 1.837
- Total = 100.000

**HTML**

```
<!-- Repeating Field in Rows -->
<input type="text" name="txtDistributionPerc" id="txtDistributionPerc" 
onkeypress='return chkKeys(event, "C");' maxlength="7" 
onblur="txt_blur_calculateFundingTotal(this);"></input>
```

**JavaScript JQuery**

```
// Filters out invalid keystrokes
function chkKeys(e,type){
    var keynum = e.keyCode;
    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);

    switch (type){
        case 'C':   /* currency ($, numbers, .) */
            valChk = /[0-9\$\.]/;
            return valChk.test(keychar);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

//Calculates a specific one based on the element passed
function txt_blur_calculateFundingTotal(ele)
{
    if(ele)
    {
        var total = 0.000;
        $(ele).closest('table').find('input[name=txtDistributionPerc]').each(function (i) {
            this.value = formatCurrency(this.value, 3, '.', '');
            var tmp = parseNumber(this.value);
            if(tmp < 0.000 || tmp > 100.000) { 
                this.value = '0.000'; 
                tmp = 0.000;
            }
            total+=tmp;
        });
        $(ele).closest('table').find('input[name=txtTotalPerc]').val(formatCurrency(total, 3, '.', ''));
        if(total != 100.000 && total != 0.000)
        {
            $(ele).closest('table').find('input[name=txtTotalPerc]').addClass('error');
            $(ele).closest('table').find('input[name=txtTotalPercValidated]').val('');
        }
        else
        {
            $(ele).closest('table').find('input[name=txtTotalPerc]').removeClass('error');
            $(ele).closest('table').find('input[name=txtTotalPercValidated]').val('true');
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks for looking.

Comment: what is the value you get if you do a console.log(total); after the .each is done? does it equal 100? I'm asking because I'm wondering if the addition is not working (rounding error) or the if check is not working right

Comment: What's the source of `formatCurrency`?

Comment: That's how computers work. Floating point numbers are base 2 amounts with limited precision that don't necessarily map to base 10 numbers.

Comment: `console.log(63.877 + 34.286 + 1.837); // 100.00000000000001`

Comment: You are mixing numbers and strings-there are no trailing zeroes after a decimal point of a number. To work to a precision of three decimal points, use Math.round((n*1000)/1000)).

Comment: Thanks everyone we are getting really close. I added :     
var tmp = Math.round((tmp1 * 1000) / 1000); and this validates now but  it will also validate 100.1 really close!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem
Maybe it helps you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the values by 1000 and work with integers.

It seems it has to be with float values.